# Create a Vertica spatial table and intersect with a point

Tags: vertica, vertica-place

I have a polygon table that looks like:

[image: tableu polygon table]

My database is Vertica and I am new with it. I want to create a table that groups all the points and create polygon, the polygon will be used to check if a latitude and longitude point is in the polygon or not.

How to create this select? I understand that there is group by concatenate function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use Vertica Place for this. You can find the installation guide [here](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/#Authoring/Place/InstallingPlaceOverview.htm%3FTocPath%3DVertica%2520Place%7CVertica%2520Place%2520Installation%2520Overview%7C_____0).

You also might need to change those `,` to `.` as I'm not sure how to specify a custom delimiter for polygons and they might interfere (or what data types you are using, etc). Also, there are other supported spatial functions that might be better, so you might want to look around the API a bit.

Basically first you need to define your polygon table:

```
CREATE TABLE regions (gid INT, geog GEOGRAPHY);
```

Then you insert into it all your polygons.  Note that I am using GROUP_CONCAT, which you may need to install from the [strings package](https://github.com/vertica/Vertica-Extension-Packages/tree/master/strings_package).

```
INSERT /*+ DIRECT */ regions
SELECT "POLYGON NUMBER", ST_GeographyFromText('POLYGON( (' || polygon_text || ') )') 
FROM (
  SELECT "POLYGON NUMBER", GROUP_CONCAT( longitude || ' ' || latitude ) 
         over ( partition by "POLYGON NUMBER" order by "POINT ORDER" ) polygon_text 
  FROM mytable
) x;

COMMIT;
```

You'll need to index them:

```
SELECT STV_Create_Index(gid, geog USING PARAMETERS index='my_regions', 
       overwrite=true, max_mem_mb=256) OVER() FROM regions;
```

Then create a table of points you want to check:

```
CREATE TABLE points (gid INT, geog GEOGRAPHY);
```

Add points:

```
INSERT INTO points VALUES (100, ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(-91.217706 43.50055)') );
INSERT INTO points VALUES (101, ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(-93.217706 43.70055)') );

COMMIT;
```

Look for intersections:

```
SELECT gid AS pt_gid, 
       STV_Intersect(geog USING PARAMETERS index='my_regions') AS pol_gid
FROM points ORDER BY pt_gid;
```